# how to use getSupportMediaController

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, deprecated, mediacontroller

First of all I know that it is deprecated from 26.0.1 so i followed some link and it bring me to [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#getMediaController()) .I was following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030) tutorial but some part of the program is deprecated now and the solution i find in the first link solves the issue from api 21 .So how to use this for pre-lollipop devices .

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented most of those things that are described in that article. I would say skip MediaSessionCompat and go with normal services. MediaSessionCompat 
 is not very well documented and not much written about how to used them or examples.

I would suggest just going with "normal" services. There is 2 sorts of services, bound and started. In my case i had to start and bind my service. Binding part only needed when callbacks from the service is needed. Try with simplest things, hello world and if service lifecylce behaves like you want start putting your own code into it.

Here example of what i did to start + bind the service:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundAudioService.class);
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and when binding done you can do your needed work here:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // relevant work for your service/activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        // cleanup, releasing of resources
    }
};
```

The way to launch and use notification though i found useful and work fine from that article.

The problem for me with that artice was that the service died + notification dissmissed as soon as one would navigate away from 1 activity after running that code from the tutorial.

Comment: Link only answer should be avoided: [answer]